# Where can I find the full game list of Game Design Challenge on GDC?

Tags: game-design, competition

The GDC [Game Design Challenge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Developers_Conference#Game_Design_Challenge) is very interesting, the event gives designers the opportunity to display their amazing creativity.

When I searched for the old events I could only find articles which featured one or two games, never the whole list. Is there a record of all the games that have been designed for this event throughout the last ten years?

Comment: GameCareerGuide also had (has?) a very nice game design challenge series going on. Here's their list: http://www.gamecareerguide.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1543

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: The guys closed my question may have narrower definition of game design than mine. Anyway, thanks to Alex and Marton give me useful information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've compiled the following list of all the Game Design Challenges (and there will be no more as 2013 was the last) along with their subtitle (I've had to guess a few). They all have links to articles or videos that contain info about all the entries and say which one won.

I haven't read through all of these (and I didn't watch the conference video) but all the information about the entries should be there, otherwise googling the subtitle of an event may divulge more details. I've listed the actual entries for each year and emboldened the winner, I managed to find titles for most of the entries but a few were not mentioned.

- [The Game Design Challenge 2013: Humanity’s Last Game](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/04/04/how-jason-rohrer-won-the-game-design-challenge/) ([2](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/189547/))

  - Fleeting - Harvey Smith
  - No Survivor - Steve Meretzky
  - The Quoggle Invasion - Erin Robinson
  - *Unknown Title* - Will Wright
  - **A Game For Someone - Jason Rohrer**
  - Ludosapiens - Richard Lemarchand
- [The Game Design Challenge 2012: Upgrade Humanity in 60 Seconds Flat](http://interactive.usc.edu/2012/03/12/the-game-design-challenge/)

  - Frog Skins - Jason Rohrer
  - **The Shame Game - Richard Lemarchand**
  - *Unknown Title* - Noah Falstein
- [The Game Design Challenge 2011: Bigger Than Jesus](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1014541/The-Game-Design-Challenge-2011) ([5](http://www.forbes.com/sites/davidewalt/2011/03/07/game-design-challenge-2011-bigger-than-jesus/2/))

  - **Chain World - Jason Rohrer**
  - Propagation - Jenova Chen
  - @Messiah6502 - John Romero
- [The Game Design Challenge 2010: Real Life Perma-death](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/99115-GDC-2010-Game-Design-Challenge-Real-Life-Perma-death)

  - Last Game and Testament - Heather Kelley and Erin Robinson
  - **HeavenVille - Jenova Chen**
  - Karma - Kim Swift
- [The Game Design Challenge 2009: My First Time](http://edition.cnn.com/2009/TECH/03/27/videogame.losing.virginity/)

  - **Our first times - Heather Kelley and Erin Robinson**
  - Your First Time - Sulka Haro
  - Wait, time passes - Steve Meretzsky
- [The Game Design Challenge 2008: Inter-Species](http://www.gamasutra.com/php-bin/news_index.php?story=17562)

  - Dolphin Ride - Alexey Pajitnov
  - TrayStation- Steve Meretzky
  - **One Hundred Dogs - Brenda Braithwaite**
- [The Game Design Challenge 2007: Thread the Needle](http://uk.gamespot.com/news/gdc-07-game-design-challenge-threads-the-needle-6167147)

  - **Stitch & Cross - Alexey Pajitnov**
  - Playper - David Jaffe
  - The Tailor's Daughter - Harvey Smith
- [The Game Design Challenge 2006: The Nobel Peace Prize](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2633/gdc_the_game_design_challenge_.php)

  - **Peace Bomb - Harvey Smith**
  - Empathy - Cliff Bleszinski
  - *Unknown Title* - Keita Takahashi
- [The Game Design Challenge 2005: Emily Dickinson](http://uk.gamespy.com/articles/594/594861p1.html)

  - Inspired - Clint Hocking
  - Poetry In Motion - Peter Molyneux
  - **Emily In Your Pocket - Will Wright**
- [The Game Design Challenge 2004: The Love Story](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/187688/Video_Famous_designers_attempt_to_make_a_game_about_falling_in_love.php) ([Audio](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1013534/Game-Design-Challenge-The-Love))

  - *Unknown Title*- Raph Koster
  - ***Unknown Title* - Will Wright**
  - *Unknown Title* - Warren Spector